# HAML putting a partial inside previous div

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm using a layout for the landing area of my site, and on that I'm using the devise_controller? method to add #login & .span.offset4 that tell the Devise views to move to the middle and set a background color.

```
%body
  = render :partial => "landing/landingmenu" 
  - if devise_controller?
    #login
      .span4.offset4  
        = yield
  - else
    = yield
  = render :partial => "landing/footer"
```

And this outputs with the footer partial inside the #login div, instead of outside it:

```
<body>
  <div id="login">
    <div class="span4 offset4">...</div>
    <div class="footer">...</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've tried putting the footer partial up inside the if like this and get the same incorrectly nested HTML output:

```
%body
  = render :partial => "landing/landingmenu" 
  - if devise_controller?
    #login
      .span4.offset4  
        = yield
    = render :partial => "landing/footer" 
  - else
    = yield
    = render :partial => "landing/footer"
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent you render one time again

```
%body
  = render :partial => "landing/landingmenu" 
  - if devise_controller?
    #login
      .span4.offset4  
        = yield
      = render :partial => "landing/footer" 
  - else
    = yield
    = render :partial => "landing/footer"
```

Comment: This would correctly put the footer div inside #login, but I'm trying to make it appear outside the #login div.

Comment: Aaah ... I understand now. That's really, really weird, you may want to file an issue if you're sure you have no `#footer` (or #footer included) in your yield

Answer (score 0):

You can add the footer at the end:

```
%body
  = render :partial => "landing/landingmenu" 
  - if devise_controller?
    #login
      .span4.offset4  
        = yield
  - else
    = yield
  = render :partial => "landing/footer"
    .footer
```

Comment: It is outside the if statements in my first example, and it doesn't work :/
The 2nd example shows it inside each if statement.